# Redirecting FTP Browser Requests to HTTP

Tags: apache, http, browsers, ftp

Is there - and if yes, what is it - a solution to the following task:

I want to redirect browser requests targeting `ftp://www.example.net` to `http://www.example.com`

I am aware that `ftp://` is communicating at port 21 while HTTP is using 80.
Infrastructure is an Ubuntu Server with Apache.

Background: a FTP service that was mostly used through by visitors through a web browser is being canceled and an information page should be shown instead.

Answer (score 2):

Redirection in HTTP is done at the HTTP protocol level. FTP has no such concept which means redirection at the protocol level is not possible. You might try to offer a HTML page using FTP which contains the refresh to another page, e.g.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/" />
```

Of course this requires the user to access this HTML page which means that the FTP server must be kept active. But this would be a requirement for HTTP redirects too, i.e. you need something at the original location which tells the user to look elsewhere.